# how to get derivatives from 1D interpolation

Tags: python, scipy

Is there a way to get scipy's interp1d (in linear mode) to return the derivative at each interpolated point? I could certainly write my own 1D interpolation routine that does, but presumably scipy's is internally in C and therefore faster, and speed is already a major issue.

I am ultimately feeding a munging of the interpolated function into a multi-dimensional minimization routine, so being able to pass analytic derivatives would speed things up a lot rather than having the minimization routine try to calculate them itself. And interp1d must be calculating them internally --- so can I access them?

Comment: Not sure if that's what you're asking, but a piecewise linear function doesn't have a well-defined derivative at the interpolation nodes.

Comment: True, but I'm essentially never asking for the interpolation at a node, and the function is smoothly-varying enough that if I could just get either the right-hand derivative or left-hand derivative on the wild chance it lands on a node, that would be fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`UnivariateSpline`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline) instead of `interp1d`, and use the `derivative` method to generate the first derivative. The example at the manual page [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.derivative.html#scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.derivative) is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: Thanks! I'd avoided using a spline because I expected it to be slower and I didn't need the precision (like I said, it's fairly smooth already), but a quick timing test shows that UnivariateSpline is more efficient than interp1d, so even calculating derivatives it's still faster! (why??)

Comment: Once the fit is done, usually calculating the n-th derivative is straightforward (in theory even faster than interpolation if you use a polynomial fit, since the power of the polynomial is lower)

Comment: Re _why_: `interp1d` is using a spline fit for the quadratic and/or cubic modes anyway. The specific spline fitting routine is different, and there is *a lot* going on in interp1d itself.

Comment: Isn't interp1d using simply a linear fit in the standard case? That's what the op seems to refer to.

Comment: It's probably worth highlighting that UnivariateSpline in general (and by default) implements a *smoothing* spline (i.e., a spline fit to noisy data, with a # of knots less than the # of data), not an *interpolating* spline (# of knots = # of data). To interpolate the data, be sure to set s=0 in the call to UnivariateSpline. Perhaps CubicSpline would be better here; it interpolates, and has a .derivative method.

Comment: InterpolatedUnivariateSpline is another option; k=1 corresponds to linear interpolation.

Answer (score 3):

You can combine [scipy.interpolate.interp1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) and [scipy.misc.derivative](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.derivative.html#scipy.misc.derivative), but there is something that must be taken into account:

When calling `derivative` method with some `dx` chosen as *spacing*, the derivative at `x0` will be computed as the first order difference between `x0-dx` and `x0+dx`:

```
derivative(f, x0, dx) = (f(x0+dx) - f(x0-dx)) / (2 * dx)
```

As a result, you can't use `derivative` closer than `dx` to your interpolated function range limits, because `f` will raise a *ValueError* telling you that your interpolated function is not defined there.

So, what can you do closer than `dx` to those range limits?

If `f` is defined inside `[xmin, xmax]` (range):

1. At the range limits you can move `x0` a bit in:

   - `x0 = xmin + dx` or `x0 = xmax - dx`
2. For other points you can refine `dx` (make it smaller).

## Uniform function outside interpolation range:

If your interpolated function happens to be uniform outside the interpolation range:

```
f(x0 < xmin) = f(x0 > xmax) = f_out
```

You may define your interpolated function like this:

```
f = interp1d(x, y, bound_errors=False, fill_value=f_out)
```

## Linear interpolation case:

For the linear case it might be cheaper to calculate just once the differences between points:

```
import numpy as np
df = np.diff(y) / np.diff(x)
```

This way you can access them as the components of an array.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, internally `interp1d` uses a [BSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.BSpline.html).
The `BSpline` has a `derivative` which gives the `nu`th derivative.

So for an interploation `f = interp1d(x, y)` you can use

```py
fd1 = f._spline.derivative(nu=1)
```

However, be carful as always when using functions with leading underscore.
I don't think bounds are checked if you choose values outside the interpolation region. It also seems, that `BSpline` appends a tailing dimension, so you have to write

```py
val = fd1(0).item()
val_arr = fd1(np.array([0, 1]))[..., 0]
```