# scipy.integrate.quad with non plausible values

Tags: python, math, scipy

He guys,

I'm al little bit in trouble with math. So there is an [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74775404/) and it's not really solved. I thought about editing the old one, but I think it's even good to start a new question.

As you can see below there is an example of my experimental code. There are the functions kf and kfm. kf is a little bit funcy fancy math stuff from an engineer. kfm is just the integral of kf.

When I use the [trapezoid rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule), the value of kfm(0.05) is ~67. It's easy, because kf(0.05) is ~135 and the first step of the trapezoid is 1/2 of kf.

So I don't know why kfm (the integral of kf) is starting at zero? I think it is wrong!

```
'''python code '''

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate
import math

# umf is just the x axis for kf and kfm
list_umf = [0.05, 0.1, 0.15000000000000002, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35000000000000003, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55,
            0.6000000000000001, 0.6500000000000001, 0.7000000000000001, 0.7500000000000001, 0.8]

# the real kf function
def kf(phi):
    k = 841.17
    m1 = -0.00112
    m2 = 0.17546
    m3 = 0.01271
    m4 = 0.00116
    phi_p = 3.42
    theta_einlauf = 1200
    if phi < 0.02:
        phi = 0.02
    return k * math.exp(m1 * theta_einlauf) * (phi ** m2) * (phi_p ** m3) * math.exp(m4 / phi)
list_kf_func = [kf(x) for x in list_umf]

# the real kfm function
def kfm(u, o):
    return integrate.quad(kf, u, o)[0]

u = list_umf[0]
list_kfm_func = [kfm(u, o) for o in list_umf]

# here are some plots
plt.plot(list_umf, list_kf_func, label='kf_func')
plt.plot(list_umf, list_kfm_func, label='kfm_func')
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
```

Here is the plot, generated with the code:
[image: Here is the plot, generated with the code]

Comment: By trapezoidal rule, `0.5*(kf(0.05)+kf(0))*0.05` = 6.34. 
By the numerical integration, `list_kfm_func[0]` = 6.20. Two numerical integration agrees with each other. Thus, kfm is not start at zero and I think you did your trapezoidal rule estimation wrong.

Comment: If this is true, you made my day. My chief, Mr Dr.Ing, did a typo in his excel sheet and blamed me sustainingly to be wrong by using the scipy lib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your trapezoidal rule estimation is incorrect.

For the first `scipy.integrate` from lower limit a=0 to upper limit b=0.05,
Using trapezoidal rule,
[image]

f is but `kf()`. Thus calculating by trapezoidal rule: `0.5*(kf(0.05)+kf(0))*(0.05-0)` gives `6.342386940782528`.

In fact, if you check the output from your Python code, `kfm(0,0.05)` = `list_kfm_func[0]` = `integrate.quad(kf, 0, 0.05)[0]` = `6.204186103148345`, which agrees with the trapezoidal rule results.

### Edit

I saw your edit history of adding `u = list_umf[0]` in your question, i.e. lower limit a= 0.05. My old answer assumes a lower limit a = 0 as this code was missing in your original code, my apologies.

**However, in this case, a = b = 0.05 for the first term of `list_kfm_func`, i.e. both numerical integration method shall give 0 as lower limit equals to upper limit**, therefore, both integration still agrees with each other and your trapezoidal rule estimation stated in your question is still not correct.

By trapezoidal rule: `0.5*(kf(0.05)+kf(0.05))*(0.05-0.05)` = `0`

By `scipy.integrate`: `kfm(0.05,0.05)` = `list_kfm_func[0]` = `integrate.quad(kf, 0.05, 0.05)[0]` = `0.0`

Comment: What you doesn't mentioned is, that I called integrate.quad(kf, u, o) at frist with u = o. And this is 0 (zero). This is my major problem.

Comment: `list_kfm_func[0]` is `kfm(0,0.05)` as `list_umf[0]=0.05`, check your code.

Comment: no, list_kfm_func = [kfm(u, o) for o in list_umf]

Comment: Your trapezoid rule calculation is still not right for the first term of `list_kfm_func[0]` even if you add the line `u = list_umf[0]` there, of course, the integral would be zero (irrespective of what numerical integration method is used) as the lower limit of integral = upper limit of integral.....

Comment: your answer is really good. so I accept it.  But the main mistake I done was the first step. It was like kfm(u, u) and this is 0. thanks for your answer and discussion.